# Eclipse Adobe plugin causes crash

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, eclipse-plugin, adobe, flexbuilder

I installed the Adobe Flash Builder 4.5 which includes the eclipse plugin.
I want 2 use my existing eclipse, so I copied the contents of plugin and features folder to existing eclipse folder.
I see the Flex features in Eclipse, but trying to open the Flex Builder Path causes eclipse to crash. Error Message is :

"Please uninstall and reinstall the product
If this problem still occurs, please contact Adobe technical support for help, and mention the error code shown at the bottom of this screen.

Error : 1
http://www.adobe.com/support/ "

How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copying those folders manually is not the correct approach. Navigate to the "utilities" folder inside the Flash Builder 4.5 installation directory and find a file called "Adobe Flash Builder 4.5 Plug-in Utility.exe" (or similar if on Mac). Double-click that file and it will launch an installer. Simply select the folder where your Eclipse installation resides and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of the Flash Builder installer.  Make sure that you downloaded the Plugin version; and not the stand alone version.  The plugin version will ask you where you eclipse directory is located.

You can download from the [Adobe web site](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash_builder).

You should not have to move any directories manually.

Comment: This option was removed from the installer in Flash Builder 4.5.

Comment: Interesting; I had no idea.  I do see on the web site that the plugin version and the standalone are available as two separate downloads.

Comment: There is 1 package to download and it has utility to install as plugin.

Comment: @Andy My original answer stated that; but Cliff corrected me, so I checked on the Adobe web sit and changed my answer.  For Flash Builder 4.5; there are two separate downloads--one for plugin and one for stand alone.  I even linked to the download page if you want to check it out yourself.